# MySQL: SUM data from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have a db for a menu which tracks clicks on it.  The menu has categories and subcategories and I'm trying to get the amount of clicks for each category but in the db, the clicks will register to the subcategory if the item is in one, otherwise the clicks are counted in the category.  I have a query that will get clicks for all subcategories (`category_type` 3) but I need to add them with the clicks from their parent category (`category_type` 2).  There is a table called `CategoryHierarchy` that maps each category to it's parent category.  This is what I have:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`MenuEntryAnalytics`.`opened`), 0) AS `clicks`,
  `Categories`.`id`, 
  `Categories`.`name`,
  `Categories`.`category_type`,
  `CategoryHierarchy`.`parent_id` AS `parent` 
FROM `MenuEntryAnalytics` 
  INNER JOIN `MenuEntries`  
      ON `MenuEntryAnalytics`.`menu_entry_id` = `MenuEntries`.`id` 
  LEFT JOIN `MenuEntryToCategory` 
      ON `MenuEntryAnalytics`.`menu_entry_id` = `MenuEntryToCategory`.`menu_entry_id` 
  RIGHT JOIN `Categories` 
      ON `MenuEntryToCategory`.`category_id` = `Categories`.`id` 
  RIGHT JOIN `CategoryHierarchy`
      ON `Categories`.`id` = `CategoryHierarchy`.`category_id` 
WHERE `Categories`.`category_type` = 3 
GROUP BY `id`;
```

Results:

```
clicks  id  name                  type parent
=============================================
2032    3   Appetizers              3   2
455     4   Salads                  3   2
680     6   Sandwiches              3   5
424     7   Burgers                 3   5
584     9   Pizza                   3   8
466     10  Kids Menu               3   8
1445    12  Soda                    3   11
1089    13  Signature Cocktails     3   11
391     14  Bottled Beer            3   11
167     15  Wine                    3   11
0       17  Events                  3   16
0       18  Sponsors                3   16
186     19  Dessert                 3   11
621     26  Restaurants             3   22
263     27  Bars                    3   22
112     28  Services                3   25
254     29  Amenities               3   25
67      30  Exclusive Benefits      3   25
190     31  Area Attractions        3   24
14      32  Entertainment           3   24
2       33  Shopping                3   24
117     34  Transportation & Tours  3   24
471     35  Mixed Drinks            3   11
541     36  Draft Beer              3   11
```

if I `GROUP BY` `parent` then I can get most of what I need (all the clicks from subcategories of each category) but this doesn't get the clicks counted towards categories (as opposed to subcategories, i.e. `category_type` 2).  I'm stuck trying to add that part in, all I can think of is using a subquery  but there's no way of identifying which category I'm looking at, thus I get a subquery with multiple rows.

PS I do not have permission to restructure the db.

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of `parent=2` and `type=2`?

Comment: The sum of the clicks for `category_type = 3` who's `parent_id` is a category with `category_type = 2`

Comment: So the sum of all `category_type = 3` with the same `parent_id` + the clicks on the category with the `id` equal to that `parent_id`

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent ID is in the same namespace as the ID, you can simply use IFNULL to pick the parent if it exists, or otherwise the ID.  And use that as your grouping strategy.

You may also want to select the same data out as an actual column.

GROUP BY
  IFNULL(`CategoryHierarchy`.`parent_id`, `Categories`.`id`, `CategoryHierarchy`.`parent_id`)

Comment: The problem is that the `category_type` 2 (top level categories) will have a `parent_id` that points to the menu its in.  So it wouldn't ever be null in the rows I'm looking for.

Comment: In that case I would use IF(category_type=2,id,parent_id) and use WHERE to restrict to columns of 2 or 3.  You can also nest IF() or CASE() if you needed to match more than 2 values.